# GridView dynamic population

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I am working on activity that connects to flickr via web service, gets photos and displays them in GridView. The GridView is not static as in all available examples, but dynamic and loads data retrieved from the service. Retrieval and setting up of GridView seems to work, but loading the images does not. When I debug activity I don't hit breakpoint in Adapter's getView method.

I tried just loading the example ImageAdapter and it works fine with sample photos. So may be something to do with threading or timing of AsyncTask?

[Here is the code](http://pastebin.com/Fc5aeUHB)

I tried moving set up of GridView and Adapter to AsyncTask:

```
   `protected void onPostExecute(List result) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        adapter = new PhotosAdapter(activity, result);

        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
        activity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }`
```

This seems to work, however, I don't feel as this is a right solution.

Comment: I'm kinda confused. So what is your end question? If you are asking if it is okay to set the adapter like you did of course. That's fine. I can tell you now you're going to run into problems when you change orientation (your async task will run each time you switch orientation). However, everything else seems fine to me :) if you want help with handling asynctasks and orientatiion changes let me know and i can provide you some code in a little bit!

Comment: Thanks. My question was that if I am not creating and setting adapter as I showed in the second snippet, but rather do that in onCreate() method and use onPostExecute() as means of signaling Adapter that model changed and view needs to update how come it does not work? I thought that when I fire notifyDataSetChanged() that is what triggers GridView to update itself. May be I am wrong in my assumption - in JFace Content Providers work kind of like I described so I assume that's how it works with Android.

Comment: I am writing this on a phone can't seem to edit. Regarding orientation problems. I haven't studied orientation that much yet because my first app targets only tablets. But please share your knowledge.

Comment: If you are assigning a new adapter (ex. gridview.setAdapter(new PhotosAdapter()) the gridview will automatically update. The call to notifyDataSetChanged is only if the current adapter's dataset has been modified in any way that requires the view to re-draw.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Tviv3TgB here is an example of one of my classes that makes use of an async task and is aware of orientation changes. The async task gets stored and passed along to the new activity instance. This activity then re-attaches itself to the async task to allow the onComplete methods to function within the new activity instance. It's rather simple. Once you understand this one its very simple to implement it on your own.